# Is there a way to record a whole session of git-bash in windows?

Tags: windows, logging, git-bash

I wonder if there is a way to record or make a kind of log-file from a whole session in git-bash (on windows7). I'm looking for something like the [script](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_script.htm) command in *nix.

Maybe is there a way to install or add other *nix commands into git-bash?

Comment: Beside http://superuser.com/a/431093/141, I don't know.